# Mysql Correlated Query Error

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I am trying to pair records according to four conditions, one of which requires a one-level correlated subquery to match a +/- date range condition.

Why is the `old.stdt` unknown in the subquery's `where` clause? Thank you.

Here are both data and query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sbids`;
CREATE TABLE `sbids` (
   `bid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ctle` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `stype` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
   `sbid` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `stdt` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `sedt` date DEFAULT NULL  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `sbids` VALUES 
   ( 11228,  8367, 'RRR', 'A', 11495, '2012-02-01', '2014-01-01'),
   ( 11228,  8367, 'RRR', 'A',  8182, '2014-03-01', '2015-02-01'),
   ( 11228,  8367, 'CCC', 'B', 29256, '2014-09-01', '2015-08-31'),
   ( 11228, 18030, 'RRR', 'A', 23319, '2013-01-01', '2013-11-01'),
   ( 11228, 18030, 'CCC', 'A', 25304, '2014-01-01', '2014-11-01'),
   ( 11228, 18030, 'CCC', 'A', 25304, '2015-01-01', '2015-11-01');

drop table if exists prd;
create table prd as
select
      old.bid, 
      old.sid,
      old.sbid as old_sbid,
      old.ctle as old_ctle, 
      old.stype as old_stype,
      old.stdt as old_stdt, 
      old.exdt as old_exdt,
      can.sbid as can_sbid, 
      can.ctle as can_ctle, 
      can.stype as can_stype,
      can.stdt as can_stdt, 
      can.exdt as can_exdt
   from 
      sbids old 
         inner join ( select 
                            innerT.bid, 
                            innerT.sid, 
                            innerT.ctle,
                            min(innerT.stdt) as stdt
                         from 
                            sbids innerT 
                         where 
                            abs(datediff( old.stdt , innerT.exdt )) <= 65
                         group by 
                            innerT.bid, 
                            innerT.sid, 
                            innerT.ctle ) can 
            on old.bid  = can.bid  
           and old.sid  = can.sid  
           and old.ctle = can.ctle
```